# Getting a ledger report from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql, vba

Hey I'm relatively new to programming in php/mysql. I'm moving our db over to mysql from Access, where I'm relatively knowledgeable in vba.

The question I have is that I'm keeping records for individual cash ledgers. the transactions are stored in a db structured like:

**tblclientpctransactions**

```
transactionid
clientid -fk
date
description
depositamount
withdrawlamount
```

What I need to do is generate a ledger for a specific time range and present it chronologically show the information and have another field that shows the balance up to that point. aka

> date| clientid | description | depositamount | withdrawlamount | runningbalance

In access/vba I used the dsum() function to get the values for the specific row, not sure how to accomplish this is php.

Comment: where does the initial balance come from for line 1 of the ledger? do you just start from $0?

Comment: Initial balance is 0. When funds are added I typically then add a deposit marked with "initial deposit"

Comment: but what if that initial deposit was in '11 and you're limiting yourself to '12 data only? somehow you have to get that previous to make the '12 query data come out right.

Comment: What i was doing in access was run a function similar to 

`dsum('depositamount-withdrawlamount',tblpctransactions,"clientid="&[clientid] & "date <#"&[GroupingDate]&"#"`

so no matter what time range I was searching the report was always doing a calculation of values < the specific row date value. So the balance was accurate at each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in MySql to get your report data:

```sql
SELECT `date`,
       `clientid`,
       `description`,
       `depositamount`,
       `withdrawlamount`,
       (@rt:=@rt + `depositamount` - `withdrawlamount`) AS runningbalance
FROM `transactions`, (SELECT @rt:=0) rt
WHERE `date` < CURDATE() AND
      `clientid` = 1
ORDER BY `date`
```

Change `CURDATE()` with your report date.

Now, given that you have following data in your table:

```
transactionid clientid date       description depositamount withdrawlamount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1        2013-01-01 NULL               100.00            0.00
2             1        2013-01-05 NULL                50.00           20.00
3             1        2013-01-07 NULL                 0.00           30.00
4             1        2013-01-15 NULL               200.00            0.00
5             1        2013-01-20 NULL                 0.00           50.00
```

That will be your output:

```
date       clientid description depositamount withdrawlamount runningtotal
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-01 1        NULL               100.00            0.00       100.00
2013-01-05 1        NULL                50.00           20.00       130.00
2013-01-07 1        NULL                 0.00           30.00       100.00
2013-01-15 1        NULL               200.00            0.00       300.00
2013-01-20 1        NULL                 0.00           50.00       250.00
```

You can then use the query in your php script like this:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$client_id = 1;
$report_date = date('Y-m-d');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT `date`,
           `clientid`,
           `description`,
           `depositamount`,
           `withdrawlamount`,
           (@rt:=@rt + `depositamount` - `withdrawlamount`) AS runningbalance
    FROM `transactions`, (SELECT @rt:=0) rt
    WHERE `date`     < :report_date AND
          `clientid` = :client_id
    ORDER BY `date`");

$query->execute(array(':report_date' => $report_date, ':client_id' => $client_id));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//your code to render the report goes here
```

All error handling and checks are skipped for brevity's sake.